Finding a derivative for option pricing
I am trying to find the derivative of the expression below wrt $S$:
$$
e^{-dt}N(x)
$$
where $x$ is defined as:
$$
\frac{\ln({\frac{S}{K}})}{\sigma\sqrt{t}}
$$
and $N(x)$ is the cumulative of the normal distribution function.
I am getting really confused as I am not sure if I need to take the derivative of the parentheses and do $N()$ of that or perhaps need to do something else. Any help is appreciated

Are you familiar with the chain rule?

Well, I used it in high school but am obviously a bit rusty. So one needs to do:
N'(x) * x'

Yes exactly. And the derivative of the cumulative normal is the normal distribution.
